# How did Millikan consider utilizing oil to help determine the charge of the electron?

Tags: physics, experimental-physics, atomic-theory

Robert Millikan's oil drop experiment help to find the charge of electrons using oil. An x-ray was aimed at the oil drops to give them a charge, and the droplets were attracted to the negative plate. How did Millikan think of oil droplets; could he not have considered any other substance to carry a charge?

Comment: "The oil was of a type usually used in vacuum apparatus and was chosen because it had an extremely low vapour pressure." Reading the wikipedia makes one wonder what more could be added at this point.